# asp.net MVC Controllers and authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorization

I have a bunch of controllers and related views that need to have role based authentication applied on them. I am thinking of having a base controller with the [authorize] property definition on it so that I can have all controllers that inherit from that base class be available only after login. I have tested this to be working. I am not sure if this is the best practice or if there will be any pit falls going ahead in this approach.

In the future I will need to have certain pages be accessible to only users within a particular role. The list of roles will be from a database table. so instead of changing all the related controllers I just make that change in the base controller that it inherits from. Is this the right way to go about doing it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7):

You can combine any number of `Authorize` attributes.

i.e. You can have a  `Authorize` attribute on your base controller and a more specific one on another controller (for instance specifying a role) and a most specific one on a controller action (specifying a role or a user)

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{}

[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
public class AdminController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Roles="SuperUser")]
    public ActionResult SuperSecret()
    {}
}
```

It will check all attributes and only revoke access if any of the attributes fail.

> In the future I will need to have certain pages be accessible to only users within a particular role.

That's how role based authentication works.

> The list of roles will be from a database table.

Load the roles into a custom `IPrincipal` in the method `OnPostAuthenticate` in global.asax.

> so instead of changing all the related controllers I just make that change in the base controller that it inherits from.

I don't follow you on this requirement. Do you want to avoid specifying roles on your controllers?

Comment: The topic starter wanted to avoid attaching a list of roles to every controller of his, but to specify the roles grouping somewhere else. Otherwise your suggestion is perfect (and a default one for the authorization scenario)

Comment: Hi is there an example of using the custom IPrincipal that you speak of in the OnPostAuthenticate method in global.asax. As far as I know the iPrincipal stores a HttpContext.Current.User object. How do I assign roles from my AppRoles table to it?

Comment: There are several examples here at SO. Search for `custom principal onpostauthenticate` or read about `IPrincipal` in MSDN

Comment: I checked this out over the weekend... http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC  ... what do you think of this approach? It basically overrides the asp.net Roleprovider class. I tried calling two different secure pages.. but the call to the GetRolesForUser(..) method in my CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider  class was called only once. So that means just one call to the database to get UserRoles ... Could there be something wrong with this approach that I am not seeing now, that made you decide to go with IPrincipal instead?

Answer (score 1):

It's all right to use a base controller class for your controllers.

However, I don't think you should tie your controllers' **inheritance** to your roles hierarchy. It doesn't seem clean to me.

I'd implement an inheritance tree of attributes, like:

```
class NormalUserRolesAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
class AdvancedUserRolesAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
class AdminUserRolesAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
```

with slightly different `OnAuthorization` behavior and then mark your controllers with those attributes.

Comment: Can you explain what advantages that gives in contrast to `[Authorize(Roles = "AdvancedUser")]`? Seems to me that you just complicate things.

Comment: Please see my comment to your answer :)

Comment: Still. Your attributes does the same thing as my suggestion. I just recommend loading the roles into a `IPrincipal` since it's used by all security features in .NET

Comment: My approach allows you to avoid distributing `[Authorize(Roles="admin1,admin2,admin3,superadmin,hyperadmin,backdoor")]` across the entire project, and keep the roles list in some one place (inside the `AdminRolesAttribute` definition), that's all

Comment: It's just role inheritance. Create a role called `SuperAdmins` which includes all users from role `Admin1`, `Admin2` etc. And use `Authorize(Roles="SuperAdmins")]`. The code belongs in a `IAuthorizationService` and not in several authorization attributes.

Comment: Yes, this is a cleaner way, I admit.